# SASS Compass image-width and image-height not working in Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass

In my Rails 4 project, I have this in my `Gemfile`..

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'compass-rails'
```

...this in my `application.sass` file...

```
@import "compass"
```

...and this in my SASS `style.sass` file...

```
.background
  $image: asset-path("my-image.jpg")
  background: url($image)
  width:  image-width($image)
  height: image-height($image)
```

With the above code, I get this error in my browser...

```
Error compiling CSS asset, Type error: no implicit conversion of nil into String (in /Users/.../style.sass)
```

It seems that the Compass functions of `image-width` and `image-height` are not able to access the `my-image.jpg` file.  If I comment them out, I am able to get the image, but am unable to make use of its width & height using Compass. I would very much like to be able to use that Compass functionality. Thanks.

Comment: I then changed `gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'` to `gem 'sass-rails''` (& bundled) and I still get the same error.

Comment: What is the result of the asset-path call?  The image-width and image-height functions expect a path that's relative to whatever your image_path is set to in your config.rb

Comment: I do get the desired image from the asset-path call.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
.background
  $image: "my-image.jpg"
  background: image-url($image)
  width:  image-width($image)
  height: image-height($image)
```

I think it is because compass' image-width and image-height already take into account the asset-pipeline. Have fun.